# Safe Alternative To mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

Hi guys just want to ask this after hours of `mod_rewrite` frustration and reading tons of 
questions about it on [stackoverflow](http://www,stackoverflow,com) because i tried everything and it didn't work with me. I don't know why, but i had enough so i searched about alternative and am asking here today for opinions. I came up with the following method.method

First assume I have this URL

```
http://www.domain.com/articles/6
```

and I have a `articles.php` page that will take the ID from this URL and pull the article
content from the database (`mod_rewrite` fails in here), so this is a little solution:

```
$article_id=explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
show_article($article_id[3]);
```

the `show_article()` function will simply take the id and query the database for the article content and I read that the server will not understand that articles is a php page so a little solution too

```
<FilesMatch "^articles$"> 
  <  ForceType application/x-httpd-php >
</FilesMatch>
```

so two questions :

1- will this solution affect indexing my website pages from search engines spiders ?

2- is this a good solution or `mod_rewrite` is better?

**Note:am sorry if the question not will formatted am not good in formatting if you can make  it look better i will appreciate it really sorry**

Comment: Check out http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html it redirects all traffic to index.php and then routes according to rules (you have something like that). Although mod_rewrite isn't hard to "learn"...

Comment: thanks but i don't want to use zend framework and i know mod_rewrite isn't hard to "learn" but it's not working with me on basic rewriting

Comment: I'm not saying that, Zend or any other framework, look at the principle.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^articles/([0-9]+)$ article.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: ah sorry i got it i will see that but what do you think about the method i talked about the problem man isn't rewriting rule it in the server i think

Comment: i tried a lot of rewriting rules but it didn't work with me i don't know why i tried examples from the net and it didn't work either that's why am searching for other methods

Answer (score 1):

Don't give up with `mod_rewrite`, it's a bit non-intuitive but *VERY* powerful and useful piece of software! You'll never get so clean solution in application regarding URL manipulation. To your question:

1) no, it'll not affect indexing. Both your solution and the one involving `mod_rewrite` are for web spiders transparent,

2) `mod_rewrite` is definitely better

I do recommend you to ask question regarding your problems with `mod_rewrite` not doing what you want. I'm pretty sure you'll sort it out with someone.